# Redirect from home url to url+anchor

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, anchor, redirect

How do I redirect a visitor who enters the website example.com to example.com#start ?
But only if it is example.com and not example.com#about or example.com#contact

I have tried using

```
window.location.hash="start"
```

but when i type in example.com#contact it redirects to example.com#start

and i have also tried

```
    if(window.location.hash != ''){ 
    window.location.hash="start";
}
```

But that doed not work at all.

I dont know if the solution should be javascript, php or htaccess. Does anyone know a smooth solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code checks if hash is NOT equal to '', which returns true if the hash is set. Therefor it will always redirect to start.

You should use the following:

```
if(window.location.hash == ''){ 
    window.location.hash="start";
}
```

Comment: No problem. After long coding days, we all make mistakes like these!

Answer (score 0):

use 
    window.location.href="www.mypage.com";

the hash which you are using just add a hash sign after the url ie: www.mypage.com#
the window.location.href will locate to new page or url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you want to redirect with a hash, but that's none of my business of course. ^^

Your second solution was somewhat correct, but you used '!=' when it should've been '=='.
If I understand correctly, you want to redirect the page to example.com#start if there is no hashtag present.
This should work:

```
if(window.location.hash == '')
{
    window.location.hash = "start";
    //If it doesn't work, try adding this here: window.location.reload();
}
```